# asihttprequest from request finished delegate

Tags: iphone, ios

I am connecting web service using asihttprequest.I consumed the service and get data from server using request finished delegate.Now I am getting userID data from the server. Based on this userID , how to create another asihttprequest  to server for retrieve data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the first **asihttprequest response**, parse out request parameters for next api  and then send asihttprequest similar to your first request like this :

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:self.url];

[request setDelegate:self];
[request setRequestMethod:@"GET"];
[request startSynchronous];
```